# Is it possible to dual boot osx using a VHD as the second partition?

Tags: mac-osx, vhd, boot

I know this can be done using Hyper-V but is this possible using vmware or something similar with OSX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid not, sorry (I've not even heard of that as a hack).

Comment: ah well... cheers anyway.. [back to the drawing board]